# Batch renaming files with a modification time restriction

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I wish to rename multiple (many) files, according to their modification datetime. That is, I wish to provide a date (say, `2014-31-03`), and for that date, replace the substring `a` to the substring `bc` in any of the files whose modification date was that date.

For example, suppose the output of `ls -latr --time-style=long-iso` is as follows:

```
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 3 bach bach 4096 2014-04-01 10:02 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-03-31 10:02 a.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-03-31 10:02 a.2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-03-31 10:02 bc.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-04-01 10:02 a.3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-04-01 10:02 bc.2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-04-01 10:02 bc.3
drwxrwxr-x 2 bach bach 4096 2014-04-01 10:08 .
```

then the output after the modification should be as follows:

```
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 3 bach bach 4096 2014-04-01 10:02 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-03-31 10:02 bc.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-04-01 10:02 a.3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-04-01 10:02 bc.2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-04-01 10:02 bc.3
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-04-01 10:12 bc.1
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bach bach    0 2014-04-01 10:12 bc.2
drwxrwxr-x 2 bach bach 4096 2014-04-01 10:12 .
```

I do not care about the case for which there is more than one appearance of the substring `a` in the name of a file. It's ok if it will replace only the first occurrence. If it makes it much easier, I'm also ok with assuming the substring appears at the beginning of the filename, but I can't assume it is of fixed length.

Comment: Whether the duplicate same file name are present in the same directory?

Comment: Well, just like any other rename, it should override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This find (GNU) should work:

```
find . -type f -newermt 2014-03-30 ! -newermt 2014-04-01 -exec bash -c 'f="$1"; n="bc.${f##*.}"; mv "$f" "$n"' - '{}' \;
```

Comment: This is simply great.

Comment: I think you have a missing `"` there... in `n=`.

Comment: And you may also need to put `/` after the sharp in `n=`, as find returns names with `./` prefix (on my ubuntu, at least).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one using `find`and bash parameter expansion inside a loop:

```
$ ls
a.file1.txt  a.file2.txt  a.file3.txt  b.file4.txt
b.file5.txt  b.file6.txt  c.file7.txt  c.file8.txt  c.file9.txt

$ files=($(find . -type f -newermt 2014-04-01 ! -newermt 2014-04-02))
$ for file in "${files[@]}"; do
> [[ "$file" =~ a. ]] && mv "$file" "${file/a./bc.}"
> done
$

$ ls
b.file4.txt  b.file5.txt  b.file6.txt  bc.file1.txt
bc.file2.txt  bc.file3.txt  c.file7.txt  c.file8.txt  c.file9.txt
```